# Remove duplicate observations based on set of rules

Tags: r, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicate observations from a data set based on my variable, id. However, I want the removal of observations to be based on the following rules. The variables below are id, the sex of household head (1-male, 2-female) and the age of the household head. The rules are as follows. If a household has both male and female household heads, remove the female household head observation. If a household as either two male or two female heads, remove the observation with the younger household head. An example data set is below.

```
id = c(1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,8,9,10)
sex = c(1,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,1)
age = c(32,34,54,23,32,56,67,45,51,43,35,80,45)
data = data.frame(cbind(id,sex,age))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this by first ordering the `data.frame` so the desired entry for each `id` is first, and then remove the rows with duplicate `id`s.

```
d <- with(data, data[order(id, sex, -age),])
#    id sex age
# 1   1   1  32
# 2   2   1  34
# 3   2   2  54
# 4   3   1  23
# 5   4   2  32
# 7   5   2  67
# 6   5   2  56
# 8   6   1  45
# 9   7   1  51
# 10  8   1  43
# 11  8   1  35
# 12  9   2  80
# 13 10   1  45
d[!duplicated(d$id), ]
#    id sex age
# 1   1   1  32
# 2   2   1  34
# 4   3   1  23
# 5   4   2  32
# 7   5   2  67
# 8   6   1  45
# 9   7   1  51
# 10  8   1  43
# 12  9   2  80
# 13 10   1  45
```

Comment: I was thinking more complicated.  Simple use of logic +1

Comment: had the same idea, but didn't come up with `-age` (+1)

Answer (score 8):

With `data.table`, this is easy with "compound queries". To order the data when you read it in, set the "key" when you read it in as "id,sex" (required in case any female values would come before male values for a given ID).

```
> library(data.table)
> DT <- data.table(data, key = "id,sex")
> DT[, max(age), by = key(DT)][!duplicated(id)]
    id sex V1
 1:  1   1 32
 2:  2   1 34
 3:  3   1 23
 4:  4   2 32
 5:  5   2 67
 6:  6   1 45
 7:  7   1 51
 8:  8   1 43
 9:  9   2 80
10: 10   1 45
```

Comment: had to remove my edit as my solution was to "keep the youngest". Read the question wrong.